# Ad network to target a specific browser only

Tags: advertising, google-ads, browsers, ad-targeting

I'm looking for an ad network which allows me to target only users with a specific browser. 
I want to advertise my online app which only works in one of the major 3 browsers.

I've looked at some of the more popular ad networks but I haven't found any.

Comment: Any particular reason why you wouldn't target the other browsers? If its a support issue, just because somebody is using firefox now, doesnt mean they wouldn't also use chrome, for example.

Comment: I'd be interested to see if you're able to find anything. Ad networks in general would avoid this kind of thing because they want to maximize coverage. If they placed your ads on only IE, for example, then their other clients are being displaced from IE browsers. That would generally upset the other subscribers.

Comment: I'm building a browser extension at the moment. There is no point advertising it to users who can not install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion:

Add some javascript to your page to determine which browser is visiting your page. If the browser matches, then display the adblock.  Otherwise, omit the adblock.

EDIT:

Ad networks that seem to support browser targetting:

OpenX:
http://www.openx.com/docs/2.8/userguide/banner%20delivery%20options

> Client - Useragent: this will enable you to target ads to matching
>   strings, which includes information about the user's browser/operating
>   system.

DoubleClick:
http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=177383

> Browsing
>
> You can target line items to a user’s browsing environment:
>
> Bandwidth: cable, DSL, etc.
>
> Browser: Android, Chrome, Firefox, Google Chrome, Microsoft Internet
>   Explorer, etc.
>
> Browser language: Chinese, English, Italian, German, etc.
>
> If a browser has more than one language assigned to it, each language
>   will generate an impression. In reports, you will see a higher number
>   of impressions attributed to "browser language" than what's shown for
>   total impressions for the line item. Operating system: Android, Apple
>   iOS, Linux, Macintosh, Microsoft Windows, etc.

Comment: I believe the question is meant the other way around. He doesn't want to show ads based on some visitor's browsers, but actually push ads, whereas the delivery network of the ads allow to target only specific browsers (so his ads do not get displayed for visitors with IE for example) ...

Comment: 'doh. Misunderstood the OP's question.

Edited answer.